# ¿Porqué esta consulta en SQL funciona bien en PhpMyAdmin pero si la ejecuto en un archivo con php no?

Tags: php

Buenos días: Tengo el siguiente código muy simple que al final muestra en pantalla el mensaje: "Actualizado correctamente" (sin comillas)

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "countier", "commx1", "countier");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}   

$sqlpol="update dt_cotizaciones set tela =REPLACE(tela, 'ó', 'o')";
echo $sqlpol;

if (mysqli_query($enlace,$sqlpol)===TRUE) 
{
    echo "Actualizado correctamente";
} else
{
    echo "no se actualizo";     
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto en mi sitio web todo parece funcionar correctamente, pero NO ACTUALIZA LA BASE DE DATOS.
Si corro el mismo SQL o QUERY

```
update dt_cotizaciones set tela =REPLACE(tela, 'ó', 'o')
```

en mi programa de mysql cliente si lo actualiza o si lo ejecuto en phpMyAdmin también lo hace correctamente.
¿Alguna orientación?

Comment: Ves algo en los logs de PHP? Ese `echo $sqlpol;` muestra algo en pantalla?

Comment: Pues no..no se ve nada anormal o un error

Comment: Pues lo único raro es que tienes backticks ` `ó`  `  en vez de comillas simples `'ó'` en el REPLACE

Comment: Procura que la collation de la base de datos coincida con la que describes ahi (UTF-8). Si no coinciden puede que ese sea el problema, es decir, la operacion se ejecuta bien en el gestor porque el propio gestor tiene las herramientas para saber que hacer, pero al hacer esto mismo en PHP quizas haya malas interpretaciones o etc. Quien sabe, es solo una especulación que facilmente puede ser errronea.

Comment: Por ejemplo, deberias verificar que en el servidor la collation este en `utf-8-general-ci` o algo asi.

Comment: Pero, ¿hay realmente filas para actualizar en tu consulta? Comparar si el resultado de `query`  es  `TRUE` **no es suficiente para saber si hubo filas actualizadas, borradas o insertadas**, pues `query` devuelve `TRUE` cuando la consulta **no falla**. Por tanto, debes usar [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php) para saber con certeza si hubo filas actualizadas. Es un **error de lógica** que hay en tu código y que deberías corregir.

Comment: Si si las hay!!!